# Chisquare for homogenity on subsets of samples for more detailed statements?

Tags: chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, contingency-tables

I have two samples of six treatment groups. The outcome is an amount of positives. The treatments in both samples are the same, the measured outcome is different but dichotomous in both samples. I want to compare if the distribution of positives in these two samples is the same.

A Chisquare is pretty good for that simple question I think. But even better would be more detailed statements like "distribution of this factor is not the same and so on".

Is it allowed to conduct multiple Chisquare-Tests on subsets of that contingency table for more detailed statements?